# Vim: in C, highlight struct name as cType

Tags: vim, struct, syntax-highlighting

I want to set up Vim for highlighting `struct` names as C type, so, I've hacked a bit on syntax script:

```
syn match cType   "\v(struct\s+)@<=[a-zA-Z0-9_]+"
syn match cType   "\v(enum\s+)@<=[a-zA-Z0-9_]+"
```

It works, but it slows down my vim really significantly! As I just type, Vim became much less-responsive on Intel Core2 Duo 2.53 GHz.

I've commented out my additions, and now it works fast again.

So, it seems, `\@<=` regexp construct is too slow to be used in syntax script. I tried to match it together with `struct` itself:

```
syn match cType   "\vstruct\s+[a-zA-Z0-9_]+"
```

But it doesn't work. Is there some other way to do this?

Comment: I experience no noticeable slow down on vim 7.4.258. What version are you currently running on? You might try updating your vim version if it is out of date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would have normally used this via `nextgroup=`, to avoid that Vim attempt to parse this everywhere:

```
syn keyword cStructure struct nextgroup=cStructName skipwhite
syn match cStructName "\h\w*" contained
hi link cStructName cType
```

But unfortunately, `syntax/c.vim` has `contains=ALLBUT` clauses which then introduce this again almost everywhere.

Therefore, I think you have to go with your second approach. What's missing (to make it work) is the clearing of the original definition, because a keyword match always has higher precedence than `:syn-match`:

```
syn match cType   "\vstruct\s+[a-zA-Z0-9_]+"
syn clear cStructure
```